# Overriding vendor scss include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sass

I'm using this gem in my rails app:
https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/

I would like to override the responsive-navbar, which is included on the last line of this file, with my own:
https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/vendor/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap-responsive.scss

Is that possible?

I've tried creating an empty file at this location: /app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_responsive-navbar.scss, but it doesnt override from the bootstrap-sass project.

Answer (score 1):

CSS overrides previous behavior if it is included after a previous style. Or in other words:

```
h1 {color:blue}
h1 {color:red}
```

Will render an h1 HTML tag red.

To override the responsive navbar you can add your changes to the application.css.scss file after

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

which compiles all the other css files in your rails app.

For what it's worth, the ruby docs recommend that you "should not rely on any particular order" in what css file gets compiled first/second (see
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives). Which may indicate why your new styling is not showing up.